# Zooming out the QChart with QRubberBand, to fit the size of the QChartView

Tags: python, qt, charts, pyqt, pyside

I have a `QChartView` with QChart. I've added `QRubberBand` to the `QChartView` to zoom the chart. Plus I overrode `wheelEvent`, to scroll the chart by X axis.

So, now I want to prevent 'outscrolling' and 'outzooming' over some value. By this names I mean, that I need to stop zoom out, when chart size reaches the original chart size (so, minimal size of the chart should be it's original size) and I need to stop scrolling event, when I reach the min or max chart value (for the same reason).

I've tried to use size of the `QChart` and `QChartView` to handle `QRubberBand` resizing as beginning, but it didn't help.

Here is my small try, but I can't find out any compatible solution for `QWheelEvent` and `QMouseEvent` (but may be there is any build in methods for these tasks, so I should not override that two events). Here is the code:

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PySide6 import QtCharts, QtGui

import random


class Chart(QtCharts.QChart):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        print(event.delta())
        if event.delta() > 0:
            self.scroll(-10, 0)
            print('e')
        else:
            self.scroll(10, 0)

    def create_series(self):
        for _ in range(2):
            series = QtCharts.QLineSeries()
            for i in range(100):
                series.append(i, random.randint(0, 10))
            self.addSeries(series)

    def setup(self):
        self.createDefaultAxes()
        self.legend().setVisible(True)
        self.legend().setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)


class ChartView(QtCharts.QChartView):
    def __init__(self, chart):
        super().__init__()
        self.setChart(chart)
        self.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.setRubberBand(QtCharts.QChartView.HorizontalRubberBand)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            if self.chart().size().width() > self.size().width():
                print("Fit")
                super().mousePressEvent(event)
            else:
                print(self, "Doesn't fit")
            print(self.chart().size().width())
            print(self.size().width())
        else:
            super().mousePressEvent(event)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

        for _ in range(2):
            chart_view = self.create_chart_view()
            self.layout.addWidget(chart_view)

        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

    @staticmethod
    def create_chart():
        chart = Chart()
        chart.create_series()
        chart.setup()

        return chart

    def create_chart_view(self):
        chart_view = ChartView(chart=self.create_chart())
        chart_view.chart().axes(Qt.Horizontal)[0].rangeChanged.connect(
            lambda: (self.sync_chart_views(chart_view))
        )

        return chart_view

    def sync_chart_views(self, source_chart_view):
        x_range = (source_chart_view.chart().axes(Qt.Horizontal)[0].min(), source_chart_view.chart().axes(Qt.Horizontal)[0].max())
        for chart_view in self.findChildren(QtCharts.QChartView):
            if chart_view != source_chart_view:
                chart_view.chart().axes(Qt.Horizontal)[0].setRange(x_range[0], x_range[1])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: It's unclear. What did you try? Why not compare the range of the data series and the range of the axis?

Comment: I've implemented this idea yesterday. Looks like it work. But i'm still trying to configure it. Bc `mousePressed` and `mouseReleased` can't prevent the gap crossing. It can set back necessary values, but the chart is 'jumping' a bit. Firstly crossing the gap and than forcing the values back causes this. May be i should set it up before drawing...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. The main thing is to call `super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)` before chart axes values setup.

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QToolTip
from PySide6 import QtCharts, QtGui


import random


class Chart(QtCharts.QChart):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.create_series()
        self.createDefaultAxes()

        self.legend().setVisible(True)
        self.legend().setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.x_min_value = self.axes(Qt.Horizontal)[0].min()
        self.x_max_value = self.axes(Qt.Horizontal)[0].max()
        self.y_min_value = self.axes(Qt.Vertical)[0].min()
        self.y_max_value = self.axes(Qt.Vertical)[0].max()
        self.layout().setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

    def create_series(self, s=3):
        for j in range(s):
            series = QtCharts.QLineSeries()
            if j == 0:
                for i in range(150):
                    if i % 10 == 0:
                        series.append(i, random.randint(0, 10))
                    else:
                        series.append(i, 2)
                self.addSeries(series)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        print(event.delta())
        if event.delta() > 0 and self.axes(Qt.Horizontal)[0].min() > self.x_min_value:
            self.scroll(-10, 0)
            print('e')
        elif event.delta() < 0 and self.axes(Qt.Horizontal)[0].max() < self.x_max_value:
            self.scroll(10, 0)


class ChartView(QtCharts.QChartView):
    def __init__(self, chart):
        super().__init__()

        self.setChart(chart)
        [series.hovered.connect(self.display_plot_value) for series in chart.series()]
        self.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.setRubberBand(QtCharts.QChartView.HorizontalRubberBand)
        self.x_min_value = chart.x_min_value
        self.x_max_value = chart.x_max_value
        self.y_min_value = chart.y_min_value
        self.y_max_value = chart.y_max_value

    @staticmethod
    def display_plot_value(point, state):
        pos = QtGui.QCursor.pos()
        if state:
            tooltip_text = f"X: {round(point.x(), 3)}, Y: {round(point.y(), 3)}"
            QToolTip.showText(pos, tooltip_text)
        else:
            QToolTip.hideText()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event) -> None:
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        if event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            if self.chart().axes(Qt.Horizontal)[0].min() < self.x_min_value:
                self.chart().axes(Qt.Horizontal)[0].setRange(self.x_min_value, self.chart().axes(Qt.Horizontal)[0].max())
            if self.chart().axes(Qt.Horizontal)[0].max() > self.x_max_value:
                self.chart().axes(Qt.Horizontal)[0].setRange(self.chart().axes(Qt.Horizontal)[0].min(), self.x_max_value)
            if self.chart().axes(Qt.Vertical)[0].min() < self.y_min_value:
                self.chart().axes(Qt.Vertical)[0].setRange(self.y_min_value, self.chart().axes(Qt.Vertical)[0].max())
            if self.chart().axes(Qt.Vertical)[0].max() > self.y_max_value:
                self.chart().axes(Qt.Vertical)[0].setRange(self.chart().axes(Qt.Vertical)[0].min(), self.y_max_value)
            return
        elif event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            if self.chart().mapToValue(event.position()).x() > self.x_max_value:
                self.chart().axes(Qt.Horizontal)[0].setMax(self.x_max_value)
            if self.chart().mapToValue(event.position()).x() < self.x_min_value:
                self.chart().axes(Qt.Horizontal)[0].setMin(self.x_min_value)
            if self.chart().mapToValue(event.position()).y() > self.y_max_value:
                self.chart().axes(Qt.Vertical)[0].setMax(self.y_max_value)
            if self.chart().mapToValue(event.position()).y() < self.y_min_value:
                self.chart().axes(Qt.Vertical)[0].setMin(self.y_min_value)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.central_widget.setObjectName('central_widget')
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        for _ in range(6):
            chart_view = self.create_chart_view()
            self.layout.addWidget(chart_view)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)


    def create_chart_view(self):
        chart = Chart()
        chart_view = ChartView(chart=chart)
        return chart_view



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```